# R-Value References C++ fact check

Tags: c++, rvalue

I am studying R-Value references at the moment, and have come to these conclusions :

-R-Value references are variables which are constructed from an R-Value (R-Values being temporary objects).

-If an R-Value is assigned to an R-Value reference, the lifetime of the R-Value is extended to match the lifetime of the R-Value reference.

-R-Value references themselves are not temporary. R values are temporary, but their lifetime is extended when assigned to an R-Value reference.

Are these correct?

Comment: See __Rvalue references__ here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

Comment: *"R-Values being temporary objects"* No. "Rvalue" is a value category, a property of an expression. "Temporary"-ness it a property of an object. Likewise, in (2), you should use "a temporary object" instead of "an rvalue". (Rvalues, and expressions in general, don't have lifetimes. Objects do.) (3) doesn't make much sense to me. *"R-Value references themselves are not temporary. R value references are temporary"* - what?

Comment: My bad, typo ^^^

Comment: technically all three are incorrect in multiple ways, but in spirit they are sort of right